# QT GUI Progress Bars

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt4

I am new to using QT and relatively new to C++. I have a vector called drives that holds all of the drive letters of a computer. I have an int called noDrives which is         drives.size(); I have set in my form in QT Designer 9 Progress bars which I will set all to invisible using

```
   ui.driveLabel1->setVisible(false);
```

I have forgotten how I would go about setting the bars to visible in a for loop. e.g. int drives = 4 so I need to turn progressBar0-4 to visible. here is what I have so far.

```
    std::vector<std::string> drives = DriveFinder();
    int noDrives = drives.size();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < noDrives ; i++){
    ui.driveBar1->setVisible(false);
    }
```

Each time around the loop I need to turn on the next driveBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly:

```
switch( i )
{
 case 1: ui.driveBar1->setVisible(false); break;
 case 2: ui.driveBar2->setVisible(false); break;
 case 3: ui.driveBar3->setVisible(false); break;
 ...
}
```

Or

```
std::vector<QProgressBar*> Bars (10);
Bars[0] = ui.driveBar1;
Bars[1] = ui.driveBar2;
...
```

Then...

```
Bars[i]->setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Sorry for the idiotic descriptions and badly worded question!